# Sqlite GLOB query not fast enough

Tags: performance, sqlite, glob

```
SELECT a.id, am.value FROM testA a 
   JOIN testA_mt am ON am.a_id = a.id 
   WHERE a.grp = 2 AND a.path GLOB 'foo/bar/*' AND am.key = "keyword"
```

`testA_mt` is a table that uses the key-pair model.

The problem is that it takes like 1 second to run.

According to http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html my GLOB query should be optimized because it meets all required criteria. The grp, path and key columns are indexed and I'm using `*` at the end.

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN looks OK:

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
SEARCH TABLE testA_mt AS am USING INDEX am_key (key=?) (~10 rows)
SEARCH TABLE testA_mt AS am USING INDEX am_key (key=?) (~10 rows)


0
0
1
1
0
0
SEARCH TABLE testA AS a USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
SEARCH TABLE testA AS a USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
```

But why is it so slow? :(

Comment: Is there an index on `testA_mt.a_id`?

Comment: yes that's indexed too

Answer (score 0):

The database estimates that using the index on `am_key` is more efficient than using the index on `path` because the former searches for an exact value.

Try running [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) so that the database has a better estimate of the indexes' selectivity.

If you want to force the join order, use [CROSS JOIN](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#table_order):

```
SELECT a.id,
       am.value
FROM testA a 
CROSS JOIN testA_mt am ON am.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.grp = 2
  AND a.path GLOB 'foo/bar/*'
  AND am.key = "keyword"
```